# Print an SQL Query in PHP so it is 'human readable'

Tags: php, sql, printing

Is there a way of printing a result from an sql query rather than just reading a resource id? Something like the way 'print_r' works?

Comment: MySQL? MSSQL? PostgreSQL? The answer is going to be specific to which SQL server you're using.

Comment: Never mind, the mysql_fetch_assoc() is exactly what im looking for :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Assuming MySQL.)</sup>

There is no native PHP functionality to iterate a resultset through a resource handle, no. You must iterate yourself using `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

On the upside, you can write a function to do it.

```
function print_rs($recordset) {
   while ($row = $recordset->fetch_assoc())
      print_r($row);
}

print_rs($db->query("SELECT * FROM `lol`"));
```

.. or something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

Are you printing the return value of `mysql_connect`? You should be looking in the output of `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.